# Compute the days from tow date inputs value

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have two different dates inputs with HTML5 calendar
One of it start date and the second is end date
I just need to compute the days when the user selects start date and end date using javascript and use if condition for example if these days great than 10 hide some elements

```js
var date1 = new Date($('#start').val());
var date2 = new Date($('#end').val());
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

```html
start
<br />
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
<br />
end
<br />
<input id="end" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
<br />
<div id="demo">the days here</div>
```

Comment: using momentjs, when working with dates, might be a simple solution to this date troubles. Lots of functions to get differences between dates in several units and much more. momentjs.com

Comment: Is there any way to do it without any js libraries?

Comment: Ofc there is, I'm preparing you a fiddle now :)

Comment: well, what's the problem with your method? https://jsfiddle.net/yaw38jrf/

Comment: Your code works, you just need to put it in some kind of listener.

Comment: I want to compute the days when the user defines the start and end date through the input calendar

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not knowing how to assign the event handlers, because your code to calculate date difference seems fine.

Comment: won't work when I choose the dates through the inputs calendar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. I bind an event to #endDate.

LInk to check --> https://jsfiddle.net/nmitic/rvpb3dfg/

```
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
<input id="end" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />

  function getDifFDate(startDate, endDate) {
  var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
  var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  return diffDays;
}

$('#end').on('change', function() {
  var date1 = new Date($('#start').val());
  var date2 = new Date($('#end').val());    

    if(getDifFDate(date1, date2) > 10) {
        console.log('do something here');
      }
});
```

***NOTE*** You should implement validations of some sort, the event should not be fired if only one input date is selected.

Comment: @KareemSultan—no, it doesn't. `Math.ceil` should be `Math.round` to account for daylight saving differences. Always rounding up will mean that going over the boundary going out of daylight saving will add an extra day. The difference in whole days between two dates is given by `Math.round((date1 - date2)/8.64e7)`.

Comment: Good catch! He should implement that. And I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code, the days will be hidden if the difference is greater than 10 days, else it will be visible.

```js
function showdiff()
{
var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("end").value);
var timeDiff = (date2 - date1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000);
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = timeDiff;
if(timeDiff > 10)
{
 document.getElementById('demo').style.display = 'none';
}
alert(timeDiff);

}
```

```html
start
<br />
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
<br />
end
<br />
<input id="end" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" />
<br />
<div id="demo">the days here</div>
<button onclick="showdiff()">Difference</button>
```